# Spring boot micro services consuming lot of memory in docker-swarm

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, microservices, docker-swarm

I have some docker swarm containers running on an **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS** instance on **Azure**. The containers are running Java Spring Boot and Netflix OSS Applications like Eureka, Ribbon, Gateway etc. applications. I obseverd my container is taking huge size of memory although services are just REST Endpoint.

I tried to limit the memory consumption by Passing Java VM args like below, but this didn't help the size didn't get changed even after.

Please note below configuration that I am using here,

Java Version : Java 8 Alpine

Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1023-azure

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

OSType: linux

Architecture: x86_64

CPUs: 32

Total Memory: 125.9GiB

Memory footprint after `docker stats`

[image: docker stats]

Java VM Arguments,

```
docker service create --name xxxxxx-service --replicas 1 --network overnet 127.0.0.1:5000/xxxxxx-service --env JAVA_OPTS="-Xms16m -Xmx32m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=48m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=8m -Xss256k -Xmn8m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=4m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=8m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=16m -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70"
```

I've tried to look at the application log files within each of the containers also but can't find any memory related errors. I also tried to limit container resources. But that also didn't work for me.

[Limit a container's resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

Any clue how I can troubleshoot this heavy memory Issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot this by using a profiler such as visualvm or jprofiler, they will show you where the memory is allocated (which types of objects etc.).

You shouldn't use it on a production system though, if possible, because profiling can be very CPU heavy.

Comment: I have checked this using visualvm, but it's not taking more than 200 MB if I run it locally. But, the Issue comes only once you deploy it on Docker, it grows to full memory allocation which is around 5-6 GB

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find out more I have used in the past is to use [AspectJ's load time weaving](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html) to add special code that adds memory information to your log files.
This will also slow down your system, but when your aspects have been weel written not so much as using a profile.

If possible profiling would be prefered - if not AspectJ load time weaving might become helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as like I mentioned earlier these are basic REST Endpoints, If I am running it locally it's just taking 150 to 200 MBs that's it. But, this issue comes only when I am deploying to Docker containers. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling actuator and compare the memory consumption values with the values generated by docker stats.

to enable actuator you could add the following dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I generally use HAL-browser for monitoring the application and consuming the actuator endpoints.
you can add that using the following maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the HAL browser you could try consuming the `/metrics` endpoint for your application.

A sample output would look like this.

```
{
    "mem" : 193024,
    "mem.free" : 87693,
    "processors" : 4,
    "instance.uptime" : 305027,
    "uptime" : 307077,
    "systemload.average" : 0.11,
    "heap.committed" : 193024,
    "heap.init" : 124928,
    "heap.used" : 105330,
    "heap" : 1764352,
    "threads.peak" : 22,
    "threads.daemon" : 19,
    "threads" : 22,
    "classes" : 5819,
    "classes.loaded" : 5819,
    "classes.unloaded" : 0,
    "gc.ps_scavenge.count" : 7,
    "gc.ps_scavenge.time" : 54,
    "gc.ps_marksweep.count" : 1,
    "gc.ps_marksweep.time" : 44,
    "httpsessions.max" : -1,
    "httpsessions.active" : 0,
    "counter.status.200.root" : 1,
    "gauge.response.root" : 37.0
}
```

this way you can monitor the memory performance of your application and find out how much memory your application is actually consuming. If this is analogous with the report generated by docker than this is a issue with your code.

However I must state that use of actuator is not production friendly as it has a significant resource overhead in itself.